# order by queries in postgres extremely slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, php-pgsql

I have a lot of order by queries in my project. I have a table with approx 100K records. After performing tests, i found out that:
1) a query with order by selecting 6 elements takes 800-900ms
2) a query without order by selecting 6 elements takes 2-3 ms

Order by seems to be very slow. After searching online i came across many things and this article:
[Article](http://www.revsys.com/writings/postgresql-performance.html)

I tried to increase working_mem but did not get good results. What can i do in order to make it faster?

Here is an example of a query:

```
select topicname,topicimage,topicowner
from topic
where active='true' and upper(topicname) like upper('%keyword%')
order by numfollowers
limit 6;
```

This query lists top 6 topics matching with the keywork

Comment: Do you have an index on the columns in your order by clause?

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing your SQL. Query optimization is done one by one, looking at the SQL and the EXPLAIN plan. There are some general guidelines, but this is not the place to discuss them. Add some specific detail if you want us to help you.

Comment: just added an example query on table topic which has 100K+ records

Comment: i have an index but it is like a bigserial id.. it is not what i am doing order by with

Comment: You need an index on the column you are ordering by or THE ONLY WAY the top 6 can be found is to look at ALL the records in the table.

Comment: Are you sure that query is slow due to the ORDER BY and not due to the LIKE? With a LIKE as that, probably indexes will be of little use... even an (numfollowers,active) index won't help much if the keyword filters out a lot of rows.

Comment: i just removed order by in that query and it ran in 2 ms, so like is not making much difference. can you give an example of how indexing can help with a query? thanks

Comment: why upper(topicname)? is your DB case sensitive? if not, please remove upper() function that will help a bit.

Comment: removed upper(), but it didnt make any difference

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: got it working... thanks.. also does indexing work when i join two tables and sort on one's index?